# Optimize MPI code for any big integer number

Tags: c, mpi

I'm trying to compute an estimation of pi using Monte Carlo methods.
The method that I used is that of the circumference inscribed into a square.

This is my simple code for the solution of the problem:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <mpi.h>

#define SEED time(NULL)

void pi_mpi_version(void) {

  unsigned int seed;
  long long int all_point;
  double x, y, start, end;
  int rank, size;
  long long int i, points = 0, all_intern;

  MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
  start = MPI_Wtime();

  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

  seed = SEED + rank;

  for ( i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++ ) {
    x = (double) rand_r(&seed) / RAND_MAX;
    y = (double) rand_r(&seed) / RAND_MAX;

    if ( x * x + y * y <= 1.0 ) points++;
  }

  MPI_Reduce(&points, &all_intern, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  all_point = 1000000000 * size;

  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  end = MPI_Wtime();

  if ( rank == 0 ) {
    printf("All intern: %lld\n", all_intern);
    printf("All points: %lld\n", all_point);
    printf("\u03C0 \u2248 %Lf\n", (long double) all_intern / all_point * 4.0);
    printf("Time elapsed: %.4f\n", end - start);
  }

  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

I try to set all varible to `long long int` but with the input `1000000000` like in the code, that return a negative number. With input up to `100000000` it seems to work.

Comment: Negative value where?

Comment: @EugeneSh. The `printf("All points: %lld\n", all_point);` print a negative value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's actually a much more interesting question than you might imagine. Your results are the combination of two issues: Overflow and a type confusion.

First the overflow part:
Numbers larger than 2147483647 can't be represented using signed 32 bit integers, which is the default size of an `int` in many C++ compilers as well as what MPI uses for the internal representation of an `MPI_INT`. So as soon as you have more than a 2-3 MPI ranks, the partial counts in the magnitude of `1000000000 * pi / 4` can still be represented as an `int`, but their sum can't - the result overflows and becomes a negative number. The same holds for the line

```
1000000000 * size
```

Without any suffix, both size and 1000000000 are of type `int`, so is their product. This computation will thus overflow, and only then will the result be stored in the larger `long long int all_points` variable.
Simple fix: Replace the computation by

```
1000000000LL * size
```

This forces the first integer to be of type `long long int`, so the whole computation won't overflow.

But your code has a second, more serious issue: Type confusion.

[`MPI_Reduce`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v4.0/man3/MPI_Reduce.3.php) expects a `void*` value for both its send and receive buffer, which means that you can use any pointer as a parameter. The type confusion now is that `MPI_Reduce` expects you to pass a pointer to an `int`, because you passed `MPI_INT` as the type argument. But the pointer you passed points to a `long long int`. What you would need to use instead is `MPI_LONG_LONG_INT`, which corresponds to the `long long int` type.

If you want to know why your code still worked for smaller iteration counts, you can read up on the binary representation of integers, especially Little/Big Endian.

Comment: Oops! The type it is my mistake of carelessness. Thanks because now does not go into overflow. In your opinion, why the code is so slowly? With the same input, with `OpenMP` it takes ~10sec.

Comment: I can only guess. How many MPI processes do you launch? It should ideally be your number of processor cores. Do you use the same total number of points both with MPI and OpenMP? Is the rest of the code identical? Do you use the same optimization level in your compiler?

Comment: 20 MPI processes. Nope, I use the flag `--oversubribe`. Yes, 20 processes also for MPI. The core of the code is the same. What kind of optimizations do you mean?

Comment: OpenMP uses only one thread per core by default. If you oversubscribe your cores, the scheduler has to switch between the processes all the time, which a) can introduce a big overhead and b) still only gives you a maximum speedup of the number of cores. Basically, if you want good parallel performance, don't oversubscribe or make sure that the parallel processes on a single core don't compete for compute time. By optimization I mean the flags `-O3` or similar.

Comment: If I run MPI with the `-np 20` flag, to compare it with the program written in OpenMP, on how many threads should I run the latter? Now, when I declare the parallel region, I set `num_threads(20)`

Comment: Performance-wise, it doesn't make much sense to run a parallel program with more threads than available cores (unless they spend most of the time waiting, but that's not the case here), otherwise you're mostly benchmarking the quality of your OS's scheduler, not your code itself. What do you want to achieve? Does your system have 20 cores?